# Angular: Select Options using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem using `<select>` with `ng-repeat` in Angular.

I'm using the following code:

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="device.remote" ng-repeat="remoteID in device.remoteIDs">
    <option value="{{ remoteID.id }}">{{ remoteID.name }}</option>
</select>
```

Angular:

```
$scope.device = response.data;
```

response.data looks like this:

```
{
    "remote": "",
    "remoteIDs": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "TEST"
        }
    ]
}
```

In the WebApp I get this result:

```
<option value="? string: ?"></option>
<option value="1" class="ng-binding">TEST</option>
```

but I dont want to show the `? string: ?`-option. How can I remove it?

I only want to display the options in `remoteIDs`

Comment: will be easy to help you if u share $scope.device data

Comment: `$scope.device` is exactly the same as `response.data`

Comment: Try use `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give a default option to the users.

You can do this by simply adding:

```
<option value="" disabled="true">Please Select</option>
```

See the example in code.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.device = {
      "remote": "",
      "remoteIDs": [
          {
              "id": "1",
              "name": "TEST"
          }
      ]
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" />

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <select ng-model="device.remote" class="mySelect">
      <option value="" disabled="true">Please Select</option>
      <option value="{{ remoteID.id }}" ng-repeat="remoteID in device.remoteIDs">{{ remoteID.name }}           </option>
  </select>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much!

Comment: But ,In this case how can we deselect an option that is already selected?I think its better to remove the `ng-disabled`.

Comment: @Mr.niks It depends on the use case. If it is required for the user to be able to deselect an option then remove the "disabled" bit on the default option.

Comment: Yes, I removed the `disabled="true"`  and it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

```
<select ng-model="device.remote>
    <option ng-repeat="remoteID in device.remoteIDs" 
        ng-if="remoteID.id" value="{{ remoteID.id }}">{{ remoteID.name }}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

don't understand why are you using `ng repeat` in the `select` element. use it in the `options`

```
 <select ng-model="device.remote">
        <option  ng-repeat="remoteID in device.remoteIDs" value="{{ remoteID.id }}">{{ remoteID.name }}</option>
    </select>
```

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
$scope.device = {
    "remote": "",
    "remoteIDs": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "TEST"
        }
    ]
}

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <select ng-model="device.remote">
    <option  ng-repeat="remoteID in device.remoteIDs" value="{{ remoteID.id }}">{{ remoteID.name }}</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove that empty option, you should take the first option as default selected. or you can give an empty option without any value
please see the snippet,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <select ng-model="device.remote" ng-repeat="remoteID in device.remoteIDs">
    <option value="{{ remoteID.id }}">{{ remoteID.name }}</option>
  </select>
  <select ng-model="device1.remote" ng-repeat="remoteID in device1.remoteIDs">
    <option value="">select</option>
    <option value="{{ remoteID.id }}">{{ remoteID.name }}</option>
  </select>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {


      $scope.device = {
        "remote": "1",
        "remoteIDs": [{
          "id": "1",
          "name": "TEST"
        }]
      };

      $scope.device1 = {
        "remote": "",
        "remoteIDs": [{
          "id": "1",
          "name": "TEST"
        }]
      };


    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```